# Инициализация (статических) переменных при конкретизации шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, инициализация, статические-члены

Объявлены следующие классы

```
template <typename T>
class Z
{
    static constexpr std::size_t N{0};

    static constexpr std::array<int, N> v_static{};
    const std::array<double, N> v{};
};

class X: Z<X>{};
```

С инициализацией N проблем не возникает

```
template<>
constexpr std::size_t Z<X>::N = 3;
```

Но как конкретизировать v и v_static для Z< X >? Следующий код не работает

```
template<>
std::array<int, Z<X>::N> Z<X>::v_static = { 4, 5, 6 };

template<>
const std::array<double, Z<X>::N> Z<X>::v = {3.14, 2.7, 0.1};
```

Comment: *"не работает"* не является описанием проблемы

Comment: @user7860670 как исправить данный код, чтобы он компилировался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как исправить данный код, чтобы он компилировался?

Определить полную специализацию `Z` для `X`:

```
template<>
class Z<X>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t           N { 3 };
    static constexpr std::array<int, N>    v_static { 4, 5, 6 };
    const            std::array<double, N> v { 3.14, 2.7, 0.1 };
};
```

> Но как конкретизировать v и v_static для Z< X >? Следующий код не работает

После того, как Вы дали определение `X`, компилятор уже сгенерировал специализацию `Z<X>`, и в этой специализации `Z<X>::N` все еще равен нулю, равно как и `Z<X>::v_static` имеет тип `std::array<int, 0>`. Когда Вы пытаетесь дать определение, после того, как *изменили* значение `N`, Вы фактически *меняете* тип `v_static` на `std::array<int, 3>`. Разумеется, это невозможно.

Что касается out-of-class определения `template<> constexpr std::size_t Z<X>::N = 3;`, оно у меня вызывает подозрения :) Давать out-of-class определение static constexpr члену-данных все еще можно (а иногда и нужно, зависит от стандарта C++), но без инициализатора, т.е.:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t Z<T>::N;
```

Comment: Да, утром я догадалась, что надо определить полную специализацию. Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Кстати, наверно, даже будет лучше вынести N в нетиповой параметр шаблона template <typename T, std::size_t N> class Z

Comment: Ну, зависит от задачи, так что Вам виднее :)